# Not able to scrape dynamic content using Selenium or BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape dynamic content from the URL: https://www.prokabaddi.com/stats/0-102-total-points-statistics. Have tried using selenium, BeautifulSoup but both fetch me an empty list.
My Code is:

```
url = "https://www.prokabaddi.com/stats/0-102-total-points-statistics"

# create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url) 
soup.find_all("div", class_="sipk-lb-playerName")
```

This returns an empty list. The data is present when I check it in the console but in the page source the data and the *div* tags are not present. I believe it has something to do with the js rendered content.

How can I extract the player names and points from this URL.

Comment: it's good practice to accept a solution if it fits your need, or at least let people know that you have a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go under the dev tools and look at XHR. you'll see the url to pull the data directly. It's returned as json, but can convert that to a table:

**Code:**

```
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = 'https://www.prokabaddi.com/sifeeds/kabaddi/static/json/1_0_102_stats.json'
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()

table = json_normalize(jsonData['data'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (table.head(5).to_string())
   match_played  player_id         player_name  position_id position_name rank team        team_full_name  team_id team_name  value
0           101        197      Pardeep Narwal          8.0        Raider    1  PAT         Patna Pirates        6       PAT   1055
1           116         81     Rahul Chaudhari          8.0        Raider    2   TT       Tamil Thalaivas       29        TT    987
2           118         41  Deepak Niwas Hooda          1.0   All Rounder    3  JAI  Jaipur Pink Panthers        3       JAI    892
3           115         26         Ajay Thakur          8.0        Raider    4   TT       Tamil Thalaivas       29        TT    811
4            88        326         Rohit Kumar          8.0        Raider    5  BEN       Bengaluru Bulls        1       BEN    689
```

And filter to only get name and points:

```
print (table[['player_name','value']])
                     player_name  value
0                 Pardeep Narwal   1055
1                Rahul Chaudhari    987
2             Deepak Niwas Hooda    892
3                    Ajay Thakur    811
4                    Rohit Kumar    689
5                 Maninder Singh    673
6               Rishank Devadiga    619
7                Kashiling Adake    612
8                     Anup Kumar    596
9           Pawan Kumar Sehrawat    572
10              Manjeet Chhillar    562
11                Sandeep Narwal    533
12                    Monu Goyat    475
13                  Jang Kun Lee    462
14                 Sachin Tanwar    456
15                   Nitin Tomar    445
16                  Jasvir Singh    412
17                 Rajesh Narwal    397
18                  Sukesh Hegde    395
19                  Meraj Sheykh    393
20                  Naveen Kumar    364
21                Vikash Kandola    358
22           Prashanth Kumar Rai    358
23                  K. Prapanjan    357
24               Shrikant Jadhav    342
25        Siddharth Sirish Desai    337
26                     Ran Singh    319
27                Ravinder Pahal    317
28                 Deepak Narwal    306
29                   Wazir Singh    300
..                           ...    ...
359         Rohit Kumar Prajapat      1
360              Kazuhiro Takano      1
361             Inderpal Bishnoi      1
362                   Amit Kumar      1
363          Sunil Subhash Lande      1
364                  Atif Waheed      1
365                  Nithesh B R      1
366  Mohammad Taghi Paein Mahali      1
367                  Yong Joo Ok      1
368               Vishnu Uthaman      1
369               Ajvender Singh      1
370                        Sanju      1
371              Ravinandan G.M.      1
372                 Navjot Singh      1
373                Parvesh Attri      1
374                Hardeep Duhan      1
375               Parveen Narwal      1
376                   Ajay Singh      1
377                  Nitin Kumar      1
378                       Jishnu      1
379                Naveen Narwal      1
380                   M. Abishek      1
381               Vikas Chhillar      1
382                         Aman      1
383                      Satywan      1
384               Vikram Kandola      1
385             Emad Sedaghatnia      1
386                Aashish Nagar      1
387        Ajinkya Rohidas Kapre      1
388                       Munish      1

[389 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible `selenium`-based solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/jamespetullo/Downloads/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.prokabaddi.com/stats/0-102-total-points-statistics')
while True:
    _b = [i for i in d.find_elements_by_tag_name('span') if 'load more' in i.text.lower()]
    if _b:
       _b[0].click()
    else:
       break

r = [{'name':i.find('div', {'class':'sipk-lb-playerName'}).get_text(strip=True), 'points':i.find('div', {'class':'sipk-lb-detailBlock sipk-lb-raidPoints'}).get_text(strip=True)} for i in 
     soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':'sipk-lb-detailItem wl-team-detail'})]
print(len(r))
```

Output:

```
389
[{'name': 'Pardeep Narwal', 'points': '1055'}, {'name': 'Rahul Chaudhari', 'points': '987'}, {'name': 'Deepak Niwas Hooda', 'points': '892'}, {'name': 'Ajay Thakur', 'points': '811'}, {'name': 'Rohit Kumar', 'points': '689'}, {'name': 'Maninder Singh', 'points': '673'}, {'name': 'Rishank Devadiga', 'points': '619'}, {'name': 'Kashiling Adake', 'points': '612'}, {'name': 'Anup Kumar', 'points': '596'}, {'name': 'Pawan Kumar Sehrawat', 'points': '572'}......]
```

Comment: This won't be able to work since we need the entire data. In this solution you can only fetch the data till the load more button. But there are many values which are displayed after you click on load more.

Comment: @ajeevanshgautam Ah yes, please see my recent edit.