# How to scrap data when the site kind of doesn't allow it?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrap data from https://gov.gitcoin.co/u/owocki/summary using python's BeautifulSoup.
image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EgUk.png

Inspecting the page with Dev tools gives an idea but with the following code, I'm not getting the full HTML code returned or as it seems the site isn't allowing scraping if I'm correct.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
content= requests.get("https://gov.gitcoin.co/u/owocki/summary").text
soup= BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>  Profile - owocki - Gitcoin Governance
</title>
<meta content="Build &amp; Fund the Open Web" name="description"/>
<meta content="Discourse 2.9.0.beta2 - https://github.com/discourse/discourse version 45c404a6c7b72bb8cb5aa9559c716bf88ce04a24" name="generator"/>
<link href="https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/standard11/uploads/gitcoin1/optimized/1X/d6503c3e8f849859f29987d8816cd515c34b04f0_2_32x32.png" rel="icon" type="image/png"/>
<link href="https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/standard11/uploads/gitcoin1/optimized/1X/d6503c3e8f849859f29987d8816cd515c34b04f0_2_180x180.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png"/>
<meta content="#ffffff" name="theme-color"/>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes, viewport-fit=cover" name="viewport"/>
<link href="https://gov.gitcoin.co/u/owocki/summary" rel="canonical">
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"WebSite","url":"https://gov.gitcoin.co","potentialAction":{"@type":"SearchAction","target":"https://gov.gitcoin.co/search?q={search_term_string}","query-input":"required name=search_term_string"}}</script>
<link href="https://gov.gitcoin.co/opensearch.xml" rel="search" title="Gitcoin Governance Search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"/>
<link data-target="desktop" href="https://sjc6.discourse-cdn.com/standard11/stylesheets/desktop_0b58afe0a66d2b0df8d67fb4eb0aa990540726fa.css?__ws=gov.gitcoin.co" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<link data-target="desktop_theme" data-theme-id="1" data-theme-name="default" href="https://sjc6.discourse-cdn.com/standard11/stylesheets/desktop_theme_1_11b2df797b4b6664ccc65d5971f471f5e0094d1f.css?__ws=gov.gitcoin.co" media="all" rel="stylesheet">   
<meta content="Gitcoin Governance" property="og:site_name">
<meta content="website" property="og:type">
<meta content="summary" name="twitter:card">
<meta content="https://sjc6.discourse-cdn.com/standard11/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/owocki/45/3597_2.png" name="twitter:image">
<meta content="https://sjc6.discourse-cdn.com/standard11/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/owocki/45/3597_2.png" property="og:image"><meta content="https://gov.gitcoin.co/u/owocki/summary" property="og:url"/>
<meta content="https://gov.gitcoin.co/u/owocki/summary" name="twitter:url"/>
<meta content="owocki" property="og:title"/>
<meta content="owocki" name="twitter:title"/>
<meta content="i spin bits for fun &amp; profit; watch out for my megabyte." property="og:description"/>
<meta content="i spin bits for fun &amp; profit; watch out for my megabyte." name="twitter:description"/>
</meta></meta></meta></meta></meta></link></link></link></head>
<body class="crawler">
<header>
<a href="/">
<img alt="Gitcoin Governance" id="site-logo" src="https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/standard11/uploads/gitcoin1/original/1X/7074a77ab7768030574e7b2aebeff2d491886f55.png" style="max-width: 150px;"/>
</a>
</header>
<div class="wrap" id="main-outlet">
<div class="user-crawler">
<img alt="owocki" src="https://sjc6.discourse-cdn.com/standard11/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/owocki/45/3597_2.png" title="owocki">
<h2 class="username">owocki</h2>
</img></div>
<p><p>i spin bits for fun &amp; profit; watch out for my megabyte.</p></p>
</div>
<footer class="container wrap">
<nav class="crawler-nav">
<ul>
<li itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
<span itemprop="name">
<a href="/" itemprop="url">Home </a>
</span>
</li>
<li itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
<span itemprop="name">
<a href="/categories" itemprop="url">Categories </a>
</span>
</li>
<li itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
<span itemprop="name">
<a href="/guidelines" itemprop="url">FAQ/Guidelines </a>
</span>
</li>
<li itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
<span itemprop="name">
<a href="/tos" itemprop="url">Terms of Service </a>
</span>
</li>
<li itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
<span itemprop="name">
<a href="/privacy" itemprop="url">Privacy Policy </a>
</span>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<p class="powered-by-link">Powered by <a href="https://www.discourse.org">Discourse</a>, best viewed with JavaScript enabled</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

How to solve this issue & get to scrap? If you suggest to use Selenium, we need to specify it's webdriver locally, I have to get this working in production, please do mention then how to achieve that.

Really thanks.

Comment: The data is probably fetched/rendered by some JavaScript, so you would need e.g. Selenium. Another approach is to inspect which urls it requests when loading the data. E.g. look for "Fetch/XHR" - there's at least an endpoint called "summary".

Comment: It is in the networking tab of chrome developer tools. Note that the terms of use of this website prohibits scraping.

Comment: Hey thanks @Jeppe for the response.
Hey anyone who would later see this: I got it solved.
I got the URL of where it fetches from the XHR/Fetch in Networking tab. There, I saw for the responses & looked for the data I wanted. I found and cross-checked it. Worked. Scraping not needed even.
Thanks :) Dev Community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

As mentioned in the comments content of website is provided dynamically, so you won't get your information with `requests` on that specific ressource / url, cause it is not able to render the website like a browser would do.

#### How to fix?

It do not need `beautifulsoup` for that task, cause there are ressources that will give you structured json data:

```
requests.get('https://gov.gitcoin.co/u/owocki.json').json()

requests.get('https://gov.gitcoin.co/u/owocki/summary.json').json()
```

#### Output

```
{'user_badges': [{'id': 4, 'granted_at': '2021-03-15T21:55:51.766Z', 'created_at': '2021-03-15T21:55:51.766Z', 'count': 1, 'badge_id': 4, 'user_id': 1, 'granted_by_id': -1}, {'id': 7832, 'granted_at': '2022-02-08T00:12:50.573Z', 'created_at': '2022-02-08T00:12:50.573Z', 'count': 1, 'post_id': 21272, 'post_number': 1, 'badge_id': 20, 'user_id': 1, 'granted_by_id': -1, 'topic_id': 8694}, {'id': 7327, 'granted_at': '2021-12-10T15:38:35.995Z', 'created_at': '2021-12-10T15:38:35.995Z', 'count': 1, 'badge_id': 37, 'user_id': 1, 'granted_by_id': -1}], 'badges': [{'id': 4, 'name': 'Leader', 'description': '<a href="https://blog.discourse.org/2018/06/understanding-discourse-trust-levels/">Granted</a> global edit, pin, close, archive, split and merge, more likes', 'grant_count': 6, 'allow_title': True, 'multiple_grant': False, 'icon': 'fa-user', 'image_url': None, 'listable': True, 'enabled': True, 'badge_grouping_id': 4, 'system': True, 'slug': 'leader', 'manually_grantable': False, 'badge_type_id': 1}, {'id': 20, 'name': 'Great Topic', 'description': 'Received 50 likes on a topic', 'grant_count': 13, 'allow_title': False, 'multiple_grant': True, 'icon': 'fa-certificate', 'image_url': None, 'listable': True, 'enabled': True, 'badge_grouping_id': 3, 'system': True, 'slug': 'great-topic', 'manually_grantable': False, 'badge_type_id': 1}, {'id': 37, 'name': 'Respected', 'description': 'Received 2 likes on 100 posts', 'grant_count': 1, 'allow_title': False, 'multiple_grant': False, 'icon': 'fa-heart', 'image_url': None, 'listable': True, 'enabled': True, 'badge_grouping_id': 2, 'system': True, 'slug': 'respected', 'manually_grantable': False, 'badge_type_id': 2}], 'badge_types': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Gold', 'sort_order': 9}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Silver', 'sort_order': 8}], 'users': [{'id': 1, 'username': 'owocki', 'name': 'Owocki', 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/owocki/{size}/3597_2.png', 'flair_name': None, 'admin': True, 'trust_level': 4}, {'id': -1, 'username': 'system', 'name': 'system', 'avatar_template': 'https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/standard11/uploads/gitcoin1/original/1X/d6503c3e8f849859f29987d8816cd515c34b04f0.png', 'flair_name': None, 'admin': True, 'moderator': True, 'trust_level': 4}], 'topics': [{'id': 8694, 'title': 'TLDR - What is Gitcoin?  [Updated Feb 2022]', 'fancy_title': 'TLDR - What is Gitcoin? :robot: [Updated Feb 2022]', 'slug': 'tldr-what-is-gitcoin-updated-feb-2022', 'posts_count': 7}], 'user': {'id': 1, 'username': 'owocki', 'name': 'Owocki', 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/owocki/{size}/3597_2.png', 'last_posted_at': '2022-02-14T14:20:48.874Z', 'last_seen_at': '2022-02-19T02:31:38.067Z', 'created_at': '2021-03-15T21:55:10.808Z', 'ignored': False, 'muted': False, 'can_ignore_user': False, 'can_mute_user': False, 'can_send_private_messages': False, 'can_send_private_message_to_user': False, 'trust_level': 4, 'moderator': False, 'admin': True, 'title': '', 'badge_count': 27, 'custom_fields': {}, 'time_read': 71929, 'recent_time_read': 25520, 'primary_group_id': None, 'primary_group_name': None, 'flair_group_id': None, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'featured_topic': None, 'bio_excerpt': 'i spin bits for fun &amp; profit; watch out for my megabyte.', 'website': 'http://gitcoin.co', 'website_name': 'gitcoin.co', 'location': 'Boulder, CO', 'bio_raw': 'i spin bits for fun & profit; watch out for my megabyte.', 'bio_cooked': '<p>i spin bits for fun &amp; profit; watch out for my megabyte.</p>', 'can_edit': False, 'can_edit_username': False, 'can_edit_email': False, 'can_edit_name': False, 'uploaded_avatar_id': 3597, 'pending_count': 0, 'profile_view_count': 1192, 'can_upload_profile_header': False, 'can_upload_user_card_background': False, 'custom_avatar_upload_id': 3597, 'custom_avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/owocki/{size}/3597_2.png', 'user_notification_schedule': {'enabled': False, 'day_0_start_time': 480, 'day_0_end_time': 1020, 'day_1_start_time': 480, 'day_1_end_time': 1020, 'day_2_start_time': 480, 'day_2_end_time': 1020, 'day_3_start_time': 480, 'day_3_end_time': 1020, 'day_4_start_time': 480, 'day_4_end_time': 1020, 'day_5_start_time': 480, 'day_5_end_time': 1020, 'day_6_start_time': 480, 'day_6_end_time': 1020}, 'accepted_answers': 0, 'featured_user_badge_ids': [4, 7832, 7327], 'invited_by': None, 'groups': []}}
```

and

```
{'topics': [{'id': 8383, 'title': 'Proposal to adjust Code of Conduct WRT Airdrops', 'fancy_title': 'Proposal to adjust Code of Conduct WRT Airdrops', 'slug': 'proposal-to-adjust-code-of-conduct-wrt-airdrops', 'posts_count': 36, 'category_id': 6, 'like_count': 147, 'created_at': '2021-08-25T17:48:20.856Z', 'has_accepted_answer': False}, {'id': 9503, 'title': 'A Vision for A Pluralistic Civilizational Scale Infrastructure for funding Public Goods', 'fancy_title': 'A Vision for A Pluralistic Civilizational Scale Infrastructure for funding Public Goods', 'slug': 'a-vision-for-a-pluralistic-civilizational-scale-infrastructure-for-funding-public-goods', 'posts_count': 22, 'category_id': 6, 'like_count': 80, 'created_at': '2021-12-24T16:45:12.082Z', 'has_accepted_answer': False}, {'id': 8694, 'title': 'TLDR - What is Gitcoin?  [Updated Feb 2022]', 'fancy_title': 'TLDR - What is Gitcoin? :robot: [Updated Feb 2022]', 'slug': 'tldr-what-is-gitcoin-updated-feb-2022', 'posts_count': 7, 'category_id': 6, 'like_count': 72, 'created_at': '2021-09-27T16:54:37.143Z', 'has_accepted_answer': False}, {'id': 8902, 'title': 'Calling all GitcoinDAO Metaverse Coordinators!', 'fancy_title': 'Calling all GitcoinDAO Metaverse Coordinators!', 'slug': 'calling-all-gitcoindao-metaverse-coordinators', 'posts_count': 14, 'category_id': 9, 'like_count': 71, 'created_at': '2021-10-28T23:00:54.169Z', 'has_accepted_answer': False}, {'id': 8497, 'title': 'What are the KPIs that GitcoinDAO Optimizes for?', 'fancy_title': 'What are the KPIs that GitcoinDAO Optimizes for?', 'slug': 'what-are-the-kpis-that-gitcoindao-optimizes-for', 'posts_count': 13, 'category_id': 6, 'like_count': 66, 'created_at': '2021-09-06T17:06:57.566Z', 'has_accepted_answer': False}, {'id': 8200, 'title': 'The Gitcoin/GitcoinDAO Egregore is Emerging', 'fancy_title': 'The Gitcoin/GitcoinDAO Egregore is Emerging', 'slug': 'the-gitcoin-gitcoindao-egregore-is-emerging', 'posts_count': 10, 'category_id': 6, 'like_count': 65, 'created_at': '2021-08-10T17:20:45.933Z', 'has_accepted_answer': False}, {'id': 9613, 'title': '2022 Roadmap & 2022 Goals', 'fancy_title': '2022 Roadmap &amp; 2022 Goals', 'slug': '2022-roadmap-2022-goals', 'posts_count': 19, 'category_id': 6, 'like_count': 46, 'created_at': '2022-01-03T16:43:05.418Z', 'has_accepted_answer': False}, {'id': 8425, 'title': 'How Do You Create A Ban on Airdrops?', 'fancy_title': 'How Do You Create A Ban on Airdrops?', 'slug': 'how-do-you-create-a-ban-on-airdrops', 'posts_count': 12, 'category_id': 6, 'like_count': 54, 'created_at': '2021-08-29T05:58:55.365Z', 'has_accepted_answer': False}, {'id': 7388, 'title': '[Proposal] Second Claim Window for $GTC', 'fancy_title': '[Proposal] Second Claim Window for $GTC', 'slug': 'proposal-second-claim-window-for-gtc', 'posts_count': 71, 'category_id': 5, 'like_count': 237, 'created_at': '2021-06-26T18:09:47.850Z', 'has_accepted_answer': False}, {'id': 7506, 'title': 'Establishing a New Process for Identify Verification Scoring (and removing troubled ID methods)', 'fancy_title': 'Establishing a New Process for Identify Verification Scoring (and removing troubled ID methods)', 'slug': 'establishing-a-new-process-for-identify-verification-scoring-and-removing-troubled-id-methods', 'posts_count': 17, 'category_id': 5, 'like_count': 47, 'created_at': '2021-06-29T17:03:02.910Z', 'has_accepted_answer': False}, {'id': 6372, 'title': '[Proposal] GR10 Matching Pool: Use Gitcoin to build GitcoinDAO', 'fancy_title': '[Proposal] GR10 Matching Pool: Use Gitcoin to build GitcoinDAO', 'slug': 'proposal-gr10-matching-pool-use-gitcoin-to-build-gitcoindao', 'posts_count': 26, 'category_id': 5, 'like_count': 111, 'created_at': '2021-06-14T21:32:52.025Z', 'has_accepted_answer': False}, {'id': 9046, 'title': 'Schelling Point Event at ETHDenver 2/17/2022 [REQUEST FOR COORDINATION]', 'fancy_title': 'Schelling Point Event at ETHDenver 2/17/2022 [REQUEST FOR COORDINATION]', 'slug': 'schelling-point-event-at-ethdenver-2-17-2022-request-for-coordination', 'posts_count': 6, 'category_id': 9, 'like_count': 20, 'created_at': '2021-11-16T03:32:07.901Z', 'has_accepted_answer': False}], 'badges': [{'id': 4, 'name': 'Leader', 'description': '<a href="https://blog.discourse.org/2018/06/understanding-discourse-trust-levels/">Granted</a> global edit, pin, close, archive, split and merge, more likes', 'grant_count': 6, 'allow_title': True, 'multiple_grant': False, 'icon': 'fa-user', 'image_url': None, 'listable': True, 'enabled': True, 'badge_grouping_id': 4, 'system': True, 'slug': 'leader', 'manually_grantable': False, 'badge_type_id': 1}, {'id': 20, 'name': 'Great Topic', 'description': 'Received 50 likes on a topic', 'grant_count': 13, 'allow_title': False, 'multiple_grant': True, 'icon': 'fa-certificate', 'image_url': None, 'listable': True, 'enabled': True, 'badge_grouping_id': 3, 'system': True, 'slug': 'great-topic', 'manually_grantable': False, 'badge_type_id': 1}, {'id': 37, 'name': 'Respected', 'description': 'Received 2 likes on 100 posts', 'grant_count': 1, 'allow_title': False, 'multiple_grant': False, 'icon': 'fa-heart', 'image_url': None, 'listable': True, 'enabled': True, 'badge_grouping_id': 2, 'system': True, 'slug': 'respected', 'manually_grantable': False, 'badge_type_id': 2}, {'id': 26, 'name': 'Campaigner', 'description': 'Invited 3 basic users', 'grant_count': 1, 'allow_title': False, 'multiple_grant': False, 'icon': 'fa-user-plus', 'image_url': None, 'listable': True, 'enabled': True, 'badge_grouping_id': 2, 'system': True, 'slug': 'campaigner', 'manually_grantable': False, 'badge_type_id': 2}, {'id': 19, 'name': 'Good Topic', 'description': 'Received 25 likes on a topic', 'grant_count': 26, 'allow_title': False, 'multiple_grant': True, 'icon': 'fa-certificate', 'image_url': None, 'listable': True, 'enabled': True, 'badge_grouping_id': 3, 'system': True, 'slug': 'good-topic', 'manually_grantable': False, 'badge_type_id': 2}, {'id': 25, 'name': 'Promoter', 'description': 'Invited a user', 'grant_count': 3, 'allow_title': False, 'multiple_grant': False, 'icon': 'fa-user-plus', 'image_url': None, 'listable': True, 'enabled': True, 'badge_grouping_id': 2, 'system': True, 'slug': 'promoter', 'manually_grantable': False, 'badge_type_id': 3}], 'badge_types': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Gold', 'sort_order': 9}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Silver', 'sort_order': 8}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'Bronze', 'sort_order': 7}], 'users': [{'id': 1, 'username': 'owocki', 'name': 'Owocki', 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/owocki/{size}/3597_2.png', 'flair_name': None, 'admin': True, 'trust_level': 4}, {'id': -1, 'username': 'system', 'name': 'system', 'avatar_template': 'https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/standard11/uploads/gitcoin1/original/1X/d6503c3e8f849859f29987d8816cd515c34b04f0.png', 'flair_name': None, 'admin': True, 'moderator': True, 'trust_level': 4}], 'user_summary': {'likes_given': 24, 'likes_received': 1036, 'topics_entered': 240, 'posts_read_count': 1555, 'days_visited': 216, 'topic_count': 66, 'post_count': 129, 'time_read': 71929, 'recent_time_read': 25520, 'can_see_summary_stats': True, 'solved_count': 0, 'topic_ids': [8383, 9503, 8694, 8902, 8497, 8200], 'replies': [{'post_number': 16, 'like_count': 12, 'created_at': '2021-08-26T18:41:25.210Z', 'topic_id': 8383}, {'post_number': 3, 'like_count': 10, 'created_at': '2022-01-03T16:49:50.145Z', 'topic_id': 9613}, {'post_number': 2, 'like_count': 10, 'created_at': '2021-08-29T13:41:42.503Z', 'topic_id': 8425}, {'post_number': 18, 'like_count': 10, 'created_at': '2021-06-28T01:53:13.183Z', 'topic_id': 7388}, {'post_number': 2, 'like_count': 9, 'created_at': '2021-06-29T17:45:32.686Z', 'topic_id': 7506}, {'post_number': 21, 'like_count': 9, 'created_at': '2021-06-18T19:32:54.151Z', 'topic_id': 6372}], 'links': [{'url': 'https://gitcoin.co/earn', 'title': 'Earn | Gitcoin', 'clicks': 105, 'post_number': 1, 'topic_id': 8694}, {'url': 'https://gitcoin.co/mission', 'title': 'Gitcoin - Support open web development. | Gitcoin', 'clicks': 90, 'post_number': 1, 'topic_id': 8694}, {'url': 'https://schellingpoint.gitcoin.co/', 'title': 'SCHELLING P0INT | 2/17/2022 @ SportsCastle in Denver CO USA', 'clicks': 86, 'post_number': 1, 'topic_id': 9046}, {'url': 'https://t.me/joinchat/DRkmhTiIH6E0MjYx', 'title': 'Telegram: Join Group Chat', 'clicks': 72, 'post_number': 1, 'topic_id': 8902}, {'url': 'https://gitcoin.co/discord', 'title': 'Gitcoin', 'clicks': 57, 'post_number': 1, 'topic_id': 8694}, {'url': 'https://gitcoin.co/learn', 'title': 'Learn | Gitcoin', 'clicks': 56, 'post_number': 1, 'topic_id': 8694}], 'most_liked_by_users': [{'id': 2044, 'username': 'Sirlupinwatson', 'name': 'Armand Brunelle', 'count': 104, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/sirlupinwatson/{size}/549_2.png', 'admin': False, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 3, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}, {'id': 5974, 'username': 'BrianMillsJr', 'name': 'BrianMillsJr.eth', 'count': 36, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/brianmillsjr/{size}/4581_2.png', 'admin': False, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 1, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}, {'id': 95, 'username': 'Fred', 'name': 'Fred', 'count': 28, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/fred/{size}/3799_2.png', 'admin': False, 'moderator': True, 'trust_level': 3, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}, {'id': 5441, 'username': 'Huxwell', 'name': 'Cali', 'count': 19, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/huxwell/{size}/3808_2.png', 'admin': False, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 2, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}, {'id': 5463, 'username': 'lee0007', 'name': 'Renee Lee', 'count': 18, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/lee0007/{size}/3839_2.png', 'admin': False, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 2, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}, {'id': 2203, 'username': 'ntquang22298', 'name': 'Quang Nguyen', 'count': 15, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/ntquang22298/{size}/2027_2.png', 'admin': False, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 1, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}], 'most_liked_users': [{'id': 17, 'username': 'Pop', 'name': 'Simona Pop', 'count': 3, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/pop/{size}/270_2.png', 'admin': False, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 4, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}, {'id': 14, 'username': 'ceresstation', 'name': 'Scott', 'count': 3, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/ceresstation/{size}/13_2.png', 'admin': True, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 2, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}, {'id': 5441, 'username': 'Huxwell', 'name': 'Cali', 'count': 2, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/huxwell/{size}/3808_2.png', 'admin': False, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 2, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}, {'id': 15, 'username': 'Anett', 'name': 'Anett Rolikova', 'count': 1, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/anett/{size}/425_2.png', 'admin': False, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 2, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}, {'id': 86, 'username': 'griff', 'name': 'Griff Green', 'count': 1, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/griff/{size}/82_2.png', 'admin': False, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 2, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}, {'id': 25, 'username': 'trent', 'name': '', 'count': 1, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/trent/{size}/32_2.png', 'admin': False, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 2, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}], 'most_replied_to_users': [{'id': 5303, 'username': 'Developer-piyush', 'name': 'PIYUSH CHOUDHARY', 'count': 4, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/developer-piyush/{size}/3571_2.png', 'admin': False, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 1, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}, {'id': 5441, 'username': 'Huxwell', 'name': 'Cali', 'count': 4, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/huxwell/{size}/3808_2.png', 'admin': False, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 2, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}, {'id': 66, 'username': 'auryn', 'name': 'auryn-macmillan', 'count': 3, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/auryn/{size}/66_2.png', 'admin': False, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 2, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}, {'id': 3, 'username': 'kyle', 'name': 'kyle', 'count': 3, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/kyle/{size}/3892_2.png', 'admin': True, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 2, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}, {'id': 5353, 'username': 'captnseagraves', 'name': 'Kevin Seagraves', 'count': 3, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/captnseagraves/{size}/3656_2.png', 'admin': False, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 1, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}, {'id': 14, 'username': 'ceresstation', 'name': 'Scott', 'count': 2, 'avatar_template': '/user_avatar/gov.gitcoin.co/ceresstation/{size}/13_2.png', 'admin': True, 'moderator': False, 'trust_level': 2, 'flair_name': None, 'flair_url': None, 'flair_bg_color': None, 'flair_color': None, 'primary_group_name': None}], 'badges': [{'id': 4, 'granted_at': '2021-03-15T21:55:51.766Z', 'created_at': '2021-03-15T21:55:51.766Z', 'count': 1, 'badge_id': 4, 'user_id': 1, 'granted_by_id': -1}, {'id': 7832, 'granted_at': '2022-02-08T00:12:50.573Z', 'created_at': '2022-02-08T00:12:50.573Z', 'count': 1, 'post_id': 21272, 'post_number': 1, 'badge_id': 20, 'user_id': 1, 'granted_by_id': -1, 'topic_id': 8694}, {'id': 7327, 'granted_at': '2021-12-10T15:38:35.995Z', 'created_at': '2021-12-10T15:38:35.995Z', 'count': 1, 'badge_id': 37, 'user_id': 1, 'granted_by_id': -1}, {'id': 15, 'granted_at': '2021-03-16T23:43:02.686Z', 'created_at': '2021-03-16T23:43:02.686Z', 'count': 1, 'badge_id': 26, 'user_id': 1, 'granted_by_id': -1}, {'id': 7068, 'granted_at': '2021-11-15T20:00:11.215Z', 'created_at': '2021-11-15T20:00:11.215Z', 'count': 3, 'post_id': 21272, 'post_number': 1, 'badge_id': 19, 'user_id': 1, 'granted_by_id': -1, 'topic_id': 8694}, {'id': 14, 'granted_at': '2021-03-16T23:43:02.646Z', 'created_at': '2021-03-16T23:43:02.646Z', 'count': 1, 'badge_id': 25, 'user_id': 1, 'granted_by_id': -1}], 'top_categories': [{'topic_count': 31, 'post_count': 40, 'id': 6, 'name': ' Meta-Governance', 'color': '652D90', 'text_color': 'FFFFFF', 'slug': 'governance-meta', 'read_restricted': False, 'parent_category_id': None}, {'topic_count': 6, 'post_count': 42, 'id': 5, 'name': ' Proposal Discussion', 'color': '0E76BD', 'text_color': 'FFFFFF', 'slug': 'governance-proposals', 'read_restricted': False, 'parent_category_id': None}, {'topic_count': 13, 'post_count': 14, 'id': 9, 'name': ' \u200d♀️ Workstream Discussion', 'color': '12A89D', 'text_color': 'FFFFFF', 'slug': 'workstream-discussion', 'read_restricted': False, 'parent_category_id': None}, {'topic_count': 8, 'post_count': 10, 'id': 8, 'name': ' Community Hangout', 'color': '3AB54A', 'text_color': 'FFFFFF', 'slug': 'community-hangout', 'read_restricted': False, 'parent_category_id': None}, {'topic_count': 7, 'post_count': 11, 'id': 12, 'name': 'Progressive Decentralization (Technical)', 'color': '808281', 'text_color': 'FFFFFF', 'slug': 'progressive-decentralization-technical', 'read_restricted': False, 'parent_category_id': 9}, {'topic_count': 1, 'post_count': 8, 'id': 13, 'name': 'Public Goods Funding', 'color': '9EB83B', 'text_color': 'FFFFFF', 'slug': 'public-goods-funding', 'read_restricted': False, 'parent_category_id': 9}]}}
```

Comment: Yeah, this question is a duplicate. Gitcoin prohibits scraping and "Performing or requesting asks through venues other than the Gitcoin Site". Not sure what "asks" refer to (or if a typo), but I don't think we should answer the question with specifics about their endpoints for that reason. Here's an almost exact duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57956324/not-able-to-scrape-dynamic-content-using-selenium-or-beautifulsoup

Comment: Yes hey the XHR/Fetch in the Qn in the link too helped. My comment top describes & I got it solved.
Thanks and yes scraping not even needed.

Comment: Ya hey @hedgehog do edit & include the link of the similar Qn and about the XHR/Fetch. I will then accept it the complete answer.
Thanks :)